# How to replace() two characters at a time using Filters and how to have a separate Badge in the context of VueJS

Tags: vue.js, filter, badge

I am displaying the text that is coming from the API as a badge and I want to filter certain things from it and I want to display the badge for each word that comes from the API.

Here is the code:

```
<span class="badge_style" id="badge" v-if="text.name">{{text.name | displayDesired}}</span>
  ...
  text: [],
  ...
  filters: {
    displayDesired: function (val){
      return val.replace(/_/g, ' ')
  },
  created() {
    this.$http.get(`/all-text`)
      .then((res) => { this.text = res.data })
      .catch((err) => {console.log(err)})
  }
  ... 
  .badge_style {
  display: inline-block;
  padding: .25em .4em;
  font-size: 85%;
  font-weight: 700;
  line-height: 1;
  text-align: center;
  white-space: nowrap;
  vertical-align: baseline;
  border-radius: .25rem;
  text-transform: capitalize;
},
#badge {
 color: white;
  font-size: 12px;
  background: blue;
}
```

{{text.name}} displays => The badge looks like this `change_plan1|change_plan2|change_plan3` this is what I am getting from the API.

{{text.name | displayDesired}} with text-transform style displays => `Change Plan1|Change Plan2|Change Plan3`here the pipe should be replaced by the space and should get a separate badge.

Expected display => The badge should look something like this `Change Plan1`  `Change Plan2`  `Change Plan3`

Please tell me how to achieve the expected output

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Convert your filter to method as following

```js
methods: {
        displayDesired: function (val){
          return val.replaceAll('_', ' ').split('|');
      },
```

as make the template as below:

```html
<span id="badge" v-if="text.name">
   <template v-for="(val, i) in displayDesired(text.name)">
      <span class="badge_style" style="margin: 2px 2px 2px;" :key="i">{{ val }} </span> 
   </template>
</span>
```

Comment: Thank you, but from your function, only the '_'  will be removed but my API returns this "changing_plan1|changing_plan2|changing_plan3", as you can see it contains pipe also in it, so I want to remove the "_" and "|" from that and display a separate badge for each. Please do help me.

Comment: @app_er corrected as per request! please mark the answer as accepted if it solves your problem.

Comment: Hello @ashwin bande, i just wanted to know how to capitalize each word using filters only, can you please show it in the same answer, that would be great.